# SQL COUNT multiplied by entries in join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to know if there is a better way to run the following query. It is returning the wrong COUNT because to get the customer's addresses I have to join the customers_addresses table and some customers have more than one address. Therefore, the COUNT is being multiplied by the number of addresses the user has. I do not want it to do this, but I still want to obtain address information. Does anyone know how I could do this?

```
SELECT 
    Customers.UserID,
    Customers.FirstName,
    Customers.LastName,
    Customers_Addresses.Address1,
    Customers_Addresses.City,
    Customers_Addresses.Region,
    TotalOrders
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Customers.UserID,
        Customers.FirstName,
        Customers.LastName,
        Customers_Addresses.Address1,
        Customers_Addresses.City,
        Customers_Addresses.Region,
        Customers.GroupID,
        COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS TotalOrders,
        SUM(Orders.TotalCost) AS TotalSalesOfAllTime
    FROM
        Orders
        INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.UserID = Orders.UserID
        INNER JOIN Groups ON Customers.GroupID = Groups.GroupID
        INNER JOIN Customers_Addresses ON Customers.UserID = Customers_Addresses.UserID
    GROUP BY Orders.UserID
) Customers
INNER JOIN Customers_Addresses ON Customers.UserID = Customers_Addresses.UserID
WHERE
    1 = 1
        AND Customers.UserID BETWEEN 2570 AND 2570
```

Comment: Start by formatting the query in your question.

Comment: Have you considered MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the Customers_Addressses table from the inner query because you can JOIN it outside in your main query what you're doing anyway so having it in the subquery is superflous.

```
SELECT 
Customers.UserID,
Customers.FirstName,
Customers.LastName,
Customers_Addresses.Address1,
Customers_Addresses.City,
Customers_Addresses.Region,
TotalOrders
FROM
(SELECT 
    Customers.UserID,
    Customers.FirstName,
    Customers.LastName,
    Customers.GroupID,
    COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS TotalOrders,
    SUM(Orders.TotalCost) AS TotalSalesOfAllTime
FROM
    Orders
    INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.UserID = Orders.UserID
    INNER JOIN Groups ON Customers.GroupID = Groups.GroupID
GROUP BY Orders.UserID
) Customers
INNER JOIN Customers_Addresses ON Customers.UserID = Customers_Addresses.UserID
WHERE Customers.UserID BETWEEN 2570 AND 2570
```

Comment: Perfect! That solved the COUNT issue but I still have the customer repeating twice because of the inner join of customer_addresses on the outer query. Is there a way to aggregate the data?